# How to use multiple regex functions to extract data in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm not much familiar with python. I'm scraping data from a school site about its address, phone, email, and the school link. I scraped the json data, and one of the keys has all these values which i have shown below.

This is the output which i receive under the key "address" :

```
<br>title='École privée'/>
17 rue Jean Gallart  <br>49650 ALLONNES  #This is the address
<br>Téléphone : <a href="tel:0241528201">0241528201</a>   #Phone no
<br>Adresse de courriel : <a href="mailto:ce.0491164Z@ac-nantes.fr">ce.0491164Z@ac-nantes.fr</a>  # Email 
<br><br><a href="./etablissement/Allonnes/ECOLE-PRIMAIRE-PRIVEE-SAINT-DOUCELIN/0491164Z.html">  #Link for school
```

Everything was in a single line, i formatted it to look clear and removed unneccesary <font  tags

I want to extract these items in the following format:

 Address : 17 rue Jean Gallart 49650 ALLONNES

 Telephone: 0241528201

 Email: ce.0491164Z@ac-nantes.fr

 Link for school = https://etablissement/Allonnes/ECOLE-PRIMAIRE-PRIVEE-SAINT-DOUCELIN/0491164Z.html

I tried extracting email using regex :

```
emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", address)
print (emails)
```

But this returns nothing

I tried extracting href tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(address, 'lxml')
for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):
print(anchor.attrs)
```

I got a close output :

```
{'href': 'tel:0241528201'}<br>
{'href': 'mailto:ce.0491164Z@ac-nantes.fr'}<br>

{'href': './etablissement/Allonnes/ECOLE-PRIMAIRE-PRIVEE-SAINT-DOUCELIN/0491164Z.html'}<br>
```

How can I extract these items one by one under different variables so that i can easily save it into a csv file?

 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect (Link pattern is sloppy) but it should do the job:

```
import re
full_string = """<br>title='École privée'/>
17 rue Jean Gallart  <br>49650 ALLONNES
<br>Téléphone : <a href="tel:0241528201">0241528201</a>
<br>Adresse de courriel : <a href="mailto:ce.0491164Z@ac-nantes.fr">ce.0491164Z@ac-nantes.fr</a>
<br><br><a href="./etablissement/Allonnes/ECOLE-PRIMAIRE-PRIVEE-SAINT-DOUCELIN/0491164Z.html">"""

addr_pattern = r'/>\s+(.*)?(?=\n<br>Téléphone)'
tel_pattern = r'<br>Téléphone.*?>(\d+)</a>'
mail_pattern = r'<br>Adresse de courriel.*?>(.*)?</a>'
link_pattern = r'<br><br><a href="(.*)?">'

print("Address: " + re.search(addr_pattern, full_string).group(1).replace('<br>', "").replace("  ", " "))
print("Telephone: " + re.search(tel_pattern, full_string).group(1))
print("Email: " + re.search(mail_pattern, full_string).group(1))
print("Link for school: " + re.search(link_pattern, full_string).group(1))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It did the job. I got an idea on how to search certain patterns. Will try to improvise.

Comment: If for whatever reason the solution doesn't work. Please let us know and update your question with more details.